# getting a warning regarding cmake whiile doing catkin_make in ROS noetic

Tags: cmake, catkin-make, ros-noetic

I've build a few workspaces for different project but i never got any error, but this time, got this msg.

```
vyas@vyas-HP-Laptop-14s:~/ROS$ mkdir -p My_turtlesim/src
vyas@vyas-HP-Laptop-14s:~/ROS$ cd My_turtlesim/
vyas@vyas-HP-Laptop-14s:~/ROS/My_turtlesim$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim
Source space: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/src
Build space: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build
Devel space: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/devel
Install space: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/install
Creating symlink "/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build"
####
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0048 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:2 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0063 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:7 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/noetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/noetic
CMake Warning (dev) at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/python.cmake:4 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
  are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:164 (include)
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:61 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.8.10", minimum required is "3") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Found PY_em: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py  
-- Using empy: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build/test_results
-- Forcing gtest/gmock from source, though one was otherwise available.
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
CMake Deprecation Warning at /usr/src/googletest/CMakeLists.txt:4 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at /usr/src/googletest/googlemock/CMakeLists.txt:45 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at /usr/src/googletest/googletest/CMakeLists.txt:56 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/src/googletest/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake:249 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
  are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/src/googletest/googletest/CMakeLists.txt:91 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.10") 
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests3
-- catkin 0.8.10
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
WARNING: package "moveit_task_constructor_core" should not depend on metapackage "moveit_planners" but on its packages instead
-- Configuring done (1.1s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build"
```

can anyone explain this, also how can i resolve this warning.
(I'm using ros noetic on ubuntu 20.04)

These are the apt packages with catkin in there name:

```
ii  python3-catkin-pkg                                                1.0.0-100                             all          catkin package library
ii  python3-catkin-pkg-modules                                        1.0.0-1                               all          catkin package library
ii  ros-noetic-catkin                                                 0.8.10-1focal.20210423.221558         amd64        Low-level build system macros and infrastructure for ROS.
ii  ros-noetic-pybind11-catkin                                        2.10.3-2focal.20230213.204608         amd64        A package vendoring recent versions of pybind11 and providing extra macros for easier integration.
```

I've updated the cmake version to 3.16.3 but i'm getting similar msg:

```
Base path: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim
Source space: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/src
Build space: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build
Devel space: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/devel
Install space: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/install
Creating symlink "/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/noetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/noetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.8.10", minimum required is "3") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Found PY_em: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py  
-- Using empy: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build/test_results
-- Forcing gtest/gmock from source, though one was otherwise available.
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.10") 
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests3
-- catkin 0.8.10
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/vyas/ROS/My_turtlesim/build"
```

Comment: My ros-noetic install does not generate those warnings for the commands that you shared. Please edit your question to list the apt packages you have installed which have `catkin` in the apt package name.

Comment: Also tell us which version of `cmake` you have installed. It should be v3.16.3. If you have upgraded cmake, your environment is not compatible with ros-noetic.

Comment: my cmake version is 3.27.7

Answer (score 0):

You should expect to have weird problems if you use an unsupported version of cmake with ros-noetic. You are expected to use the standard version from the standard ubuntu-20 apt repository.

You need to downgrade your cmake to version 3.16.3. How you do that depends on how you installed the upgrade. If you used apt to upgrade cmake, I expect that you can use apt to downgrade it.

Comment: How, can I solve this issue??

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: I've updated the question.